# Meleze.web and Web.Config transformation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, minify

I'm using the Meleze.Web library for my web application and I want to add the compression only on release builds.

I tried to do a web.config transformation but in the Web.Release.config file, when I try to do

```
<configuration>

   <system.web.webPages.razor>
      <host xdt:Transform="Replace" factoryType="Meleze.Web.Razor.MinifyHtmlWebRazorHostFactory, Meleze.Web, Version=1.4.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a868b5321967eda" />
   </system.web.webPages.razor>

</configuration>
```

gives me an error saying that the :Transform is not declared. Any help would be appreciated. Please note, this is the Web.Config in the Views folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For me, its working perfectly. Steps that I followed are here:

1. Install Meleze.Web via Package Manager Console `PM> Install-Package Meleze.Web`
2. Open `View/Web.config` and replace the `<host...../>` line inside `<system.web.webPages.razor>` with `<host factoryType="Meleze.Web.Razor.MinifyHtmlWebRazorHostFactory, Meleze.Web, Version=1.4.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a868b5321967eda" />`

That's all I did. Btw, I am using MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Web.Release.config file for transforming your Web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of 
    "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator 
    finds an attribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB" 
        connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  -->
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="Meleze.Web.Razor.MinifyHtmlWebRazorHostFactory, Meleze.Web, Version=1.4.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a868b5321967eda" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <system.web>
    <!--
      In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
      <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```